# Facebook Open Graph - See if User checked into a particular place some time

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-php-sdk, checkin

is there a way to check if a user checked into a particular place at any time in the past?

with php sdk, i can get a place info like:

```
$place = $facebook->api('/placeIDhere');
var_dump($place['checkins'])
```

this gives me the checkin count.

to get the recent checkins of a user i could do

```
$usercheckins = $facebook->api('/search?type=checkin');
var_dump($usercheckins[0]['place']['name']);
```

this gives me the last checkin by name

but is there a way to check if a user checked into a special place? `/search?type=checkin` only gives me a very small number of recent checkins and if a checkin is older than ~2-3 weeks it doesn't even appear.

thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a [FQL query](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/) against the [checkin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/checkin/) table. Something like:

```
    SELECT coords,tagged_uids,author_uid,page_id,app_id,post_id,timestamp,message 
    FROM checkin 
    WHERE author_uid = me() and page_id = 'placeID'
```

Comment: is there a way to do this with the new sdk version? tried something like that with no response: `$facebook->api('fql.query?query=xyz');`

Comment: Make sure the query you run will actually return a result by testing the same query on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/. Also, try a more basic query first.

Comment: okay, can't get this working with the php-sdk. i used file_get_contents now with the access_token from the sdk. seems working, thanks!. i'm thankful for every hint to get this working directly with the sdk

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to make the bkaid answer worked with the PHP SDK ([see on github](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)).

First, you have to check if the user is logged in or not :

```
require "facebook.php";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
    'secret' => YOUR_APP_SECRET,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        $user = null;
    }
}
```

You render the link to make him log in if he is not. And if he is, you can make the API call :

```
if (!$user) {
    echo '<a href="' . $facebook->getLoginUrl() . '">Login with Facebook</a>';
} else {
    $fql = "SELECT post_id, message FROM checkin
            WHERE author_uid = me() AND page_id = THE_PAGE_ID";

    $response = $facebook->api(array(
        'method' => 'fql.query',
        'query' => $fql,
    ));
}
```

Hope that helps !